# Highcharts : categories in format with double quotes

Tags: highcharts

I have series in the javascript using below code. Getting correct values but it is in Double quotes. So that is the reason I am not getting drilled down chart.

```
 var arrayCodeSeries = <%= serializer.Serialize(ViewData["arrayCodeSeries"]) %>;
    i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<arrayCodeSeries.length;i++)
    {
    var temp = arrayCodeSeries[i];
   temp = '['.concat(temp,']');
    arrayCodeSeries[i] = temp;

    }
```

I am getting

arrayCodeSeries[0] = "['70-158','70-177','70-181']"

```
 data = [{
                y: parseInt(arrayTotalCertificateCount[0]),
                color: colors[0],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Certificate Code',
                    categories: arrayCodeSeries[0],
                    data: [2,2,1],
                    color: colors[0]
                }
```

I tried to remove double quotes with Replace, ReplaceAll and substring functions but it gets me error like it doesn't support these functions.

Help...

Thank you..

attaching here the array :

[image: Array]

**JS Fiddle with Static data**    http://jsfiddle.net/xj6ms/1/

Comment: Could you tell me how `arrayCodeSeries` looks like? Just show a sample code by editing your question. Categories can not be string for sue, should be an array.

Comment: Hello Pawel, I have mentioned the code above, which is getting the arrayCodeSeries from the ViewData (Controller). and then I am accessing one by one series and put square brackets. I have also pasted 0th node of the array, the first series above. and now I want to apply that in the categories.

Comment: arrayCodeSeries array looks like -  arrayCodeSeries[0] = "['70-158','70-177','70-181']"       arrayCodeSeries[1] = "['70-158','70-177','70-181']"     arrayCodeSeries[2] = "['70-680']"      I want to remove double quotes from this, so that it would work fine with Highcharts categories.

Comment: I want to know what do you have in `arrayCodeSeries` after that line: `var arrayCodeSeries = <%= serializer.Serialize(ViewData["arrayCodeSeries"]) %>;`. Not when adding to drilldown.

Comment: Please check the question again.. I have added the array in the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to comment discussion:

You should change your code from:

```
for(i=0;i<arrayCodeSeries.length;i++) {
  var temp = arrayCodeSeries[i];
  temp = '['.concat(temp,']');
  arrayCodeSeries[i] = temp;
}
```

to:

```
var temp = [];
for(i=0;i<arrayCodeSeries.length;i++) {
  var items = arrayCodeSeries[i].split(',');
  temp.push(items);
}
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but getting this error. 

      var temp = [];
        for(i=0;i<arrayCodeSeries.length;i++) {
         var item = arrayCodeSeries[i];
        temp[i]([item]);
Uncaught TypeError: Property '0' of object [object Array] is not a function
        }

Comment: Answer to your question - I have 5 columns and for each of them I  have this arrayCodeSeries array(with length - 5) for categories. they are always in sequence. i have done that in .net code.

Comment: Pawel, Please check my question - I have updated it with the js fiddle. I have created it with static data so that you will get an idea what I am trying to do.

Comment: Pawel, it worked fine. Now I have last question. If array is coming as null dynamically, so I dont want to show that column. Is it possible ? because I want to show this chart for Top 5 data. But if there is less data then 5 columns, then??

Comment: Which column? arrayCodeSeries as null array? I'm sorry, could you make it a little more clear?

Comment: Powel, as we have already figured out that my data is coming dynamically in array. Array length is fixed - 5. So I have created 5 columns. But if data is coming null for one or more columns then my chart will look like this - see this fiddle : jsfiddle.net/xj6ms/2/

I want to remove empty columns, so that it will arrange other columns properly. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Powel, I got the answer from SteveP. It is working fine now. Thank you.